# Too many False Positives with Unbalanced Data

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, churn

I am trying to predict customer churn in a telco company, using R.The dataset is very unbalanced, the target is around 0.6% of the base.

- 8,746 Customers will Churn
- 1,396,664 Customers do not churn

I have trained a Random Forest in R.Prior to training, I SMOTE the training data:

```
train.smote <- SMOTE(Churn~ ., train, perc.over = 100, perc.under=200
```

This gives me a 1:1 Balance. I then train the forest using:

```
fit<- randomForest(as.factor(Churn)~.,data=train.smote,importance=TRUE, 
ntree=500)
```

When I run,

```
pred=predict(fit,newdata=test,type="class")
```

on my validation Data, I get the following Confusion Matrix:

```
             Positive    Negative
Positive     1,136,610   234,625 
Negative     3,762       5,911
```

The F Score is 0.83, the Specificity is 0.61.
However, the number of False Positives is too high (234,625).
Please suggest a method to curb these False Positives without compromising on the True Positives.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this question should be moved over to [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) or [DataScience](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/).

Anyway, there are tons of things you can do.

**Feature Extraction and Importance**, which variables are most correlated with the churn, which are less, remove the latter.

Can you extract new feature from the variables you have? This can be hard and a bit of "try and fail", but it can improve your results.

At last, try **Ensemble Models**, essentially you build several different models (best if uncorrelated with each other), and combine the results. This will boost the performance. [Ensemble Models in R](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&ei=Ad97W7jUKerhrgSV87HABw&q=ensemble%20models%20in%20r&oq=ensemble%20models%20&gs_l=psy-ab.1.0.0i203k1l10.5666.5666.0.6297.1.1.0.0.0.0.121.121.0j1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.1.121....0.O9GYC5cCllk).